# Mysql select query different tables comparison

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

first of all sorry if this question is very bad , but I 'm really confused and google doesn't help :(

I have a table named "project" which has the following columns:

```
Name  |  Description  |  Max Grade  |
  1   |  blabla       |      2      |
```

I have another table named "uploaded_projects" which has the following columng:

```
Pname  | Team Code  | Grade  |  Max Grade           |
  1    |  234       |  2     | (that's what i want) |
```

I added a foreign key constrait with the following code.

```
ALTER TABLE uploaded_projects 
ADD CONSTRAINT 'fk_u_p' FOREIGN KEY 'fk_u_p'(Pname)
REFERENCES 'project'(Name)
```

Now I want to fill the second table's column " Max Grade" with the values of 1st table's "max grade" column , which are conected through columns "Name"(1st tabled primary key) and "Pname" ( 2nd table column). How can I do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try update statement

```
UPDATE uploaded_projects, project
SET    uploaded_projects.max_grade= project.max_grade
WHERE  project.`name`= uploaded_projects.pname
```

or use join

```
UPDATE uploaded_projects AS t1
  INNER JOIN project AS t2 ON t1.pname= t2.`name`
SET t1.max_grade = t2.max_grade
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update upload_projects
Inner join project on (upload_projects.pName = project.Name )
set upload_projects.MaxGrade = project.MaxGrade
```